# How can I connect my Logitech "unifying" controller, to my Android device over Bluetooth?

Tags: usb, bluetooth

Logitech's Unifying standard seems very similar to Bluetooth(same 5-device limit, similar range, similar specs from what I've read on the Internet).

I'm trying to connect a Logitech F710 wireless controller, to my Android phone over bluetooth.

It works if I plug the "unifying" USB dongle into a USB OTG cable(micro-USB to full-USB converter) and plug said OTG in my phone. It works fine(fiddling on the controller moves things around on-screen. But I need it to work without plugging into the phone's MicroUSB port...

I've got a Samsung/Occulus Gear VR(that connects to the phone's MicroUSB port.

But when I hook up the OTG cable to my Gear VR's charging Micro-USB port, it just doesn't work. I've read on reddit that if you prevent the Occulus app from starting when you plug in your Android device(I'm using a Note 5), then the Gear VR's charging port also registers that stuff.

So any suggestions?

Comment: I believe it is not possible, as Logitech unifying is not open source, no one knows how it works technically.

Comment: There's people who've reverse-engineered the Unifying protocol, seems exactly like bluetooth - I just hope there's a Unified-to-Bluetooth hack: https://tequals0.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/reverse-engineering-logitech-unifying-usb-protocol/

Answer (score 4):

Logitech unifying devices are not compatible with Bluetooth. Your best option is to purchase a Bluetooth-compatible mouse.

Comment: I'm hoping I might be able to get a 'Unified' to Bluetooth converter. Funny thing is, when I plug the Unified USB into my phone directly(using an OTG cable), it works. ALSO works if I plug OTG into my GearVR - but ONLY if the Occulus app is force-closed.